# How can I extract the week number from java.util.Date in scala

Tags: scala, week-number, java.util.date

I already tried to use:
getWeek
getCalendarDate
and I don't want to use Calendar package (because I am using a specific software that don't allow me to use it)
Thanks in advance,

Comment: Any reason why you are using the long outdated `Date` class? [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), is much nicer to work with.

Comment: It depends an awful lot on how your weeks are and how they are numbered. Which day-of-week is the first day if the week? On which day around New Year does week 1 begin? Not everywhere in the world is the ISO standard used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.util.Calendar
import java.util.GregorianCalendar 

val calendar = new GregorianCalendar()

calendar.setTime(sail_dt)   
calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)
```

Finally I managed to find a SCALA code to cope with my problem. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the API documentation for [JavaDoc - java.util.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html)

You should be able to see that `java.utils.Date` has no method for getting week.

People generally use `Calender` for various requirements. In your case, you can use a `DateFormat` to format your `Date` object to a `String` then parse it to get the integer value.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

val date = new Date()

// if you want week in year
val formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("w")
val week1 = Integer.parseInt(formatter1.format(date))

// if you want week in month
val formatter2 = new SimpleDateFormat("W")
val week2 = Integer.parseInt(formatter2.format(date))
```

Answer (score 2):

I am sorry that I cannot write Scala code. I will have to trust you to adapt from my Java snippets.

If you can, abandon the long outdated `Date` class. Use for example `ZonedDateTime` from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API.

```
    int weekNumber = myZonedDateTime.get(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfYear());
```

The same will work with an `OffsetDateTime`, a `LocalDateTime` and a `LocalDate`. For a date or date-time today (Dec 6, 2017), you get 49.

I used [ISO 8601 weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) (Monday is the first day of week, and week 1 is the first week that has at least 4 days in January). If your weeks are different, please substitute a different `WeekFields` object, for example `WeekFields.SUNDAY_START`.

If you cannot avoid getting an old-fashioned `Date` object, convert it to a modern `Instant` and do the further operations using the modern API:

```
    ZonedDateTime converted = oldFashionedDate.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("Pacific/Nauru"));
```

Please substitute your desired time zone (provided that you didn’t want Pacific/Nauru). Once you’ve got a `ZonedDateTime`, proceed as above.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
org.threeten.extra.YearWeek.from(
    myJavaUtilDate.toInstant()
                  .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" )  )
).getWeek()
```

> 49

## `YearWeek`

The [Answer by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47678440/642706) is correct and wise.

(Java syntax here; do not know Scala)

If doing much work with weeks, and your definition of week agrees with the [ISO 8601 definition of week](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) where week # 1 contains the first Thursday and where Monday is the first day-of-week, then consider adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. That library includes many classes extending the functionality of the java.time classes. In particular is a [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html) class.

First convert the awful troubled `java.util.Date` object to java.time.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant();
```

Assign the time zone through which you want to perceive a date. A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Generate the `YearWeek` object to represent that moment’s year-week in the ISO 8601 week date system, the combination of a week-based-year and week-of-week-based-year.

```
YearWeek yw = YearWeek.from( zdt ) ;
```

If you want to represent that value with a standard ISO 8601 format, simply call [`YearWeek::toString`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html#toString--).

```
String output = yw.toString() ;
```

> 2017-W49

If you want to represent that value with the week number as an integer, call [`YearWeek::getWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html#getWeek--).

```
int weekNumber = yw.getWeek() ;
```

> 49

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

By the way, you should indeed be avoiding the `Calendar` class, as well as `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and the java.sql classes. All those troublesome old date-time classes are now legacy, entirely supplanted by the java.time classes.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).